# Kubernetes: Health checks for external Endpoints Services

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service, kubernetes-networking

I have created a `Service` with a **static** `Endpoint` that points to two public IP addresses (`A.B.C.D` and `X.Y.V.Z`).

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web-app
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: web-app
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: A.B.C.D
      - ip: X.Y.V.Z
    ports:
      - port: 80
```

Is there a health check for these IP addresses by default, what if one of the IP addresses goes down?
If there is no pre-built health check, how do I configure it?

Answer (score 1):

As per [this feature request](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/77738) in official kubernetes repo and the [comment](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/77738#issuecomment-491560980) written by ***Vllry***,

> Only ready pods have an endpoint added to the Endpoints object (there is no concept of health checks at the service/endpoint level). This allows consumers of endpoints to avoid the need to health check. So I'm afraid this would be an out-of-scope feature request.

Kubernetes doesn’t have built-in functionality to monitor the endpoints. If you need to monitor these endpoints you can use some other tools like **servicemesh** or **external monitoring tools**.